# Update a column, selected by query

Tags: sql-server, update

Just stumbled upon this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648898/sql-update-with-row-number. The second answer struck me as odd:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.CODE_DEST = x.New_CODE_DEST
FROM (
      SELECT CODE_DEST, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RS_NOM]) AS New_CODE_DEST
      FROM DESTINATAIRE_TEMP
      ) x
```

Here, a column `CODE_DEST` is updated with the value of `ROW_NUMBER()`. However, `x.CODE_DEST` itself is the result of a select query. So, I'm updating the result of a select query. Is this common practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not common but it can work.  Under certain circumstances (and I'm not sure of the rules) you can update a column from a CTE or subquery.  My guess is that it's very similar to being able to [update a view](http://sqlstudies.com/2015/09/30/updating-a-view/) and probably has the same rules.

The times I've done it it's quite a bit faster than joining back to the original table and updating it.

Comment: You are correct. The restrictions are the same as for [Updateable Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Comment: I frequently use this technique, and it's fully legal and supported.